# I couldn't achieve a server hit during GET call. What url should be given to hit the server when the page is loading (Java + Spring MVC + AngularJS)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, angular2-template

I'm new to developing Java applications. I have started coding through NetbeansIDE. I have used Java and Spring MVC framework in the front-end and Angular JS at the backend.

The project structure is,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJTAL.jpg

The pom.xml looks like :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>example1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>example1</finalName>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
</project>
```

The index.html :

```
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sample.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <p>The ID is {{greeting}}</p>
<!--            <p>The content is {{greeting.content}}</p>-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

sample.js file:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    var url = $location.absUrl();
    console.log(url);
    $http.get(url+'sampleData/string').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.greeting = response.data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
});
```

SampleClass.java :

```
package com.airhacks.ping.boundary;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod

@Controller
@RequestMapping("sampleData")
public class SampleClass {

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/string" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStringValue(){
        return "Hi Hello World! Good Morning";
    }

}
```

context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/example1"/>
```

bean.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

Please suggest me some ways to achieve a proper get call. Thanks,
Ashfaque.

Comment: `Context path="/example1"`... Where do you take this into account in the other code?

Comment: Sorry. I can't get you sir. Are you asking like for what reason this /example1 is used? it was already configured while creating the project with project name 'example1' sir.

Comment: I mean, all I see is, `url+'sampleData/string'`, so where exactly are you stuck? What errors are you getting with this code?

Comment: @John I understood that - I'm asking is there an error. Also, what url is entered to begin with so we're not guessing at `$location.absUrl();`

Comment: Add some error handling. Also can inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: @JohnD I have modified the question.

Comment: @charlietfl How to do those error handling practices on the ui side?

Comment: add a catch to `$http`

Comment: @charlietfl The catch block is executing.. It throws a catch exception I guess...

Comment: Inspect the error object for clues. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. It's up to you to do basic debugging